# How do I filter out all the fields that are of Option type in proc_macro_derive

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I'm creating my first derive macro. I'm trying to filter all non optional fields from the struct. I want to use those for the constructor. I'm not sure how I extract them. I was thinking of getting the path of the type, and to check if that path is equal to `std::option::Option`. This is not really working out. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or how I should continue?

It's all in the line with `let non_optional_field_arguments = ...`

```rust
// This function is not really interesting for this question
fn to_argument(field: &syn::Field) -> proc_macro2::TokenStream{
    let field_name = &field.ident;
    let field_type = &field.ty;
    quote! {
        #field_name : #field_type
    }
}

#[proc_macro_derive(Creator)]
pub fn derive_creator(_item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let item = parse_macro_input!(_item as DeriveInput);
    let item_ident = item.ident;

    let fields = if let syn::Data::Struct(syn::DataStruct {
        fields: syn::Fields::Named(syn::FieldsNamed {ref named, ..}),
        ..
    }) = item.data {
        named
    } else {
        panic!("You can derive only on struct!")
    };

    let field_arguments = fields.iter().map(to_argument);

    let non_optional_field_arguments = fields.iter().filter(|field| {
        return if let syn::Field{ty: syn::Type::Path(ref path), ..}= field{
            // I want to work with this, but the debug trait is not implemented
            let segments = &path.path.segments; 
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }).map(to_argument);
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Comment: The only rock-solid solution is to annotate each optional field (or all the non-optional fields, same thing). Everything else is best-effort guessing based on strings.

Comment: Ah, I go that direction as well! Thanks for the suggestion!